# Spacemacs missing some keybindings

Tags: key-bindings, spacemacs

I just installed Spacemacs v.0.300.0 but the following Spacemacs keybindings from this link do not exist:
https://www.spacemacs.org/layers/+emacs/org/README.html#key-bindings

The Key Binding tables say:

```
SPC a o l   org store link
SPC m i l   org-insert-link
```

How to trouble shoot this?
There are no install instructions so I was expecting it to work out of the box.

I am using Emacs 27.2 with Evil Spacemacs v.0.300.0 and Ivy on Linux.

**UPDATE 1:**

Maybe has something to do with this error in *dotfile-test-results*:

```
FAIL: with-eval-after-load
```

The error is generated by command dotspacemacs/sync-configuration-layers (SPC f e R) when this line is added to dotspacemacs-configuration-layers:

```
(with-eval-after-load 'org)
```

as described in   https://develop.spacemacs.org/layers/+emacs/org/README.html#important-note

Comment: Spacemacs has effectively dropped support for master and release tags. Almost every user has switched to develop branch (less bugs, better support). Have you tried that?

Comment: @TerryTsao, That's news to me.  I will give develop branch a try.

Comment: There is also separate documentation for the develop branch https://develop.spacemacs.org/layers/+emacs/org/README.html#org-mode. However, it seems that those keybindings should be available in the master and develop branches. So you probably did not install the org layer yet. (B.t.w., for quick answers, the [Spacemacs gitter](https://gitter.im/syl20bnr/spacemacs) usually is quite active).

Comment: @dalanicolai, M-x org-version prints:
Org mode version 9.5.1 (9.5.1-g36086a @ /home/wolfv/.emacs.d/elpa/27.2/develop/org-9.5.1/)
Does that mean org layer is installed?

Comment: I guess it does, because it shows that org gets installed from elpa. I realize now that you placed the line `(with-eval-after-load 'org)` in `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers`, so that is not right indeed. You should only add simply `org` there. The `(with-eval-after-load 'org)` should be placed in `dotspacemacs/user-config` and only if you want to configure some org variables. If you have more question about this, then better ask it on the [Spacemacs gitter](https://gitter.im/syl20bnr/spacemacs/)... usually quicker response, and no long converstions here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by me adding this to dotspacemacs-configuration-layers:

```
(with-eval-after-load 'org)
```

As dalanicolai suggested, I replaced that line with a simple org:

```
org
```

Now Spacemacs keybindings work as expected.